# Utilisation du mot "fatalité" pour designer mort (comme le mot anglais "fatality")

Tags: traduction, anglais, faux-amis

One of definitions of "fatality" is:

https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/fatality ; https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/fatality

> a death caused by an accident or by violence, or someone who has died in either of these ways

Can one use in this way the French word "fatalité"?
I have seen several dictionaries and it seems to me that in this context the two words are false cognates.

Nevertheless, even as an anglicism, if one says:

> Il y a des milliers de fatalités sur les routes

conveying

> There are thousands of traffic fatalities

would he be understood?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In French, "fatalité" is used to translate the English word "fate" ([Larousse](https://www.larousse.fr/dictionnaires/francais/fatalit%C3%A9/32970#:%7E:text=Destin%2C%20force%20occulte%20qui%20d%C3%A9terminerait,poussait%20vers%20un%20acte%20insens%C3%A9.)). So, saying:

> Il y a des milliers de fatalités sur les routes.

would not convey the same meaning as using "fatalities" in English. You would use the word "décès" or "morts." 
A common way of being a little less explicit when talking about death is to say "accidents mortels," referring to the accident rather than the person *(note that in that case, the total number of deaths could differ from the number of accidents, so use this phrase carefully)*.

Comment: On peut très bien avoir plusieurs décès dans un seul accident mortel. Un accident mortel est un accident dans lequel il y a eu au moins 1 décès. Donc la formule n'est pas juste moins explicite, elle ne qualifie pas la même chose.

Comment: Pas faux @LaurentS. À utiliser avec précaution alors.

Answer (score 1):

Another suggestion:

> *Chaque année, il y a des milliers de vies brisées sur les routes.*

However, that generally also includes people who survived accidents but whose destiny has been broken because of them.